# Mongoose cannot update array: undefined error

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

Please look at this code:

```
// Update route
router.put("/:comment_id", function (req, res) {
    Campground.findOneAndUpdate(
        {"_id": req.params.id, "comments._id": req.params.comment_id },
        {"$set": {"comments.$.text": req.body.comment.text}},
        function (err, campground) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("campground: " + campground); //logs campground: undefined
                console.log("comment id: " + req.params.comment_id); // logs comment id: 5a5f2ab0a6dccd210c0136de
                console.log("campground id: " + req.params.id); // logs campground id: 5a5e083af62da603900ab0d4
                res.redirect("/campgrounds");
            } else {
                res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

the ids refers to an url like this:

```
http://localhost:4000/campgrounds/5a5e083af62da603900ab0d4/comments/5a5e0845f62da603900ab0d5/edit
```

This is weird for me, why I cannot reach `campground`? In this way i cannot update the doc I need. Please help me to find a solution.

EDIT: Error provided by `console.log(err);` :

```
{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "secondo me no" at path "comments"
    at new CastError (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:27:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:158:13)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:695:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1066:15)
    at ObjectId.castForQuery (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:198:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1035:15)
    at castUpdateVal (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:345:19)
    at walkUpdatePath (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:229:22)
    at castUpdate (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:72:18)
    at model.Query._castUpdate (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2991:10)
    at castDoc (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3017:18)
    at model.Query.Query._findAndModify (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2292:19)
    at model.Query.Query._findOneAndUpdate (folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2139:8)
    at folder\node_modules\kareem\index.js:276:8
    at folder\node_modules\kareem\index.js:23:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "secondo me no" at path "comments"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"secondo me no"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'secondo me no',
  path: 'comments',
  reason: undefined }
```

@Younel this is the Edit view:

```
<% include ../partials/header %>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Edit Comment</h1>
        <div style="width: 30%; margin:25px auto;">
            <form action="/campgrounds/<%= campground_id %>/comments/<%= comment._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="comment[text]" value="<%= comment.text %>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="/campgrounds">Go Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

"secondo me no" is the `comment[text]` value

This is a github repo: https://github.com/ufollettu/YelpCamp.git (run v10/app.js)

Comment: And what about `console.log(err)` ? You know there's an error, but you're not even logging it.

Comment: you sure `req.params.id` is set as expected? It seems your program gets the comment id properly, but fails to find the Campground, which suggests the Campground id is not being properly passed to the mongoose model.

Comment: @Jeremy: I make an Edit, please see the Question above

Comment: @Sergeon I think yes: I use `var commentsRoutes = require("./routes/comments")` and `app.use("/campgrounds/:id/comments", commentsRoutes);` in my app

Comment: Ah, so it's not `undefined error`. It's clearly `Cast to ObjectId failed`. Apparently it's getting passed `"secondo me no"` as an _id

Comment: @Jeremy Thille: yes, How can I fix this? `"comments._id": req.params.comment_id` was not the correct way to pass the comment id to the campground array?

Comment: I'm thinking, but I can't figure it out. The logs are correct, real _id like `5a5e083af62da603900ab0d4`, so I have no idea where this `"secondo me no"` comes from. It may be elsewhere in your code

Comment: I think the route should be `/:comment_id/edit`

Comment: @Jeremy Thille "secondo me no" is the new value of the text field that I want to update. My fault, I wrote "new value" first. Now I Edited the Question

Comment: @YouneL `/:comment_id/edit` route (router.get()) is the Edit route. This is the Update route. I Try, but not works

Comment: You have to show the edit view to see the source of this "secondo me no"

Comment: @YouneL I provided the Comment Edit View in the Question above

Comment: @ufollettu try to cast `comment_id` manually use this syntax: `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.comment_id);`

Comment: @YouneL Tried, but same error

Comment: Look into your database if there was some `comment_id` with the value of `secondo me no`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get [your models](https://github.com/ufollettu/YelpCamp/blob/master/v10/models/campground.js) right, `comments` is not just an array but an array of [embedded documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html), so the update must be something like this:

```
Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, doc) {
    if (err || !doc) {
        ...
    }
    const comment = doc.comments.id(req.params.comment_id);
    if (!comment) {
        ...
    }
    comment.text = req.body.comment.text;
    doc.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            ...
        }
    })
})
```

For referenced documents:

```
router.put("/:comment_id", function (req, res) {
    Comment.findOneAndUpdate(
        {"_id": req.params.comment_id},
        {"$set": {"text": req.body.comment.text}},
        function (err, comment) {
            if (err) {
                ...
            } 
            res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + req.params.id);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Console says `TypeError: doc.comments.id is not a function`

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Comments in campgroundSchema should be `[commentSchema]` - the thing you commented off there.

Comment: There's no way with Referenced Docs instead of Embedded ones?

Comment: Referenced docs are stored in a separate collection. If it is what you intend to use, you will need to update the `comment` document in its own collection without even touching `Campground`.